# Step(s) wrong in solving for $x$, $5^{x+2}=4^{1-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Kindly assist me in finding my error in solving for $x$:

> $$5^{x+2}=4^{1-x}$$

My worksheet says that the answer cannot be expressed as an *exact* term, which is the same as saying the answer cannot be expressed in terms of  $\log$. Additionally, my numerical value is incorrect.

Here are my steps:

$$5^x\cdot5^2=\frac{4^1}{4^x}$$

$$5^x4^x=\frac 4{25}$$

Taking $\log_4$ of both sides:

$$x\log_4 5+x=1-2\log_4 5$$
$$x(\log_4 5+1)=1-2\log_4 5$$
$$x=\frac{-2\log_4 5+1}{\log_4 5+1}$$

Performing long division:

$$x=-2-\frac 1{\log_45+1}=-2-(\log_45+1)^{-1}$$

From this, $-2-(\log_45+1)^{-1}$ is my *exact* solution.

$-2-(\log_45+1)^{-1}$ evaluates to around $-2.463$, but the solution says $x=-0.612$

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: `Performing long division` You may want to recheck that step.

Comment: What else is incorrect?

Comment: That can't be answered until you fix the *first* wrong step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you perform long division

$$x = -2 + \frac{3}{\log_45+1}$$

Comment: That gives you the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry, I misread $3$ as $1$

Comment: oh, i made a mistake just now.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake here

$$x=\frac{-2\log_4 5+1}{\log_4 5+1}$$
$$x=\frac{-2\log_4 5-2+3}{\log_4 5+1}=\frac{-2(\log_4 5+1)+3}{\log_4 5+1}$$
$$x=-2 +\frac{3}{\log_4 5+1}$$